# Reactive Test problem with TransactionalUniAsserter

Tags: quarkus

I have problem with Reactive test for Panache Entity,  I just more or less copied sample from documentation.

The problem is that test is not executed - it should fail, but it succeeds.   Below I added one more general test which works as expected (e.g.  fails).

Problem seems to be with `TransactionalUniAsserter` - looks like jobs from it are not scheduled. UniAsserter default injected instance seems to be fine - as per second test.

```
package eu.zderadicka.mbs3;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Timeout;

import eu.zderadicka.mbs3.data.value.Genre;
import io.quarkus.test.hibernate.reactive.panache.TransactionalUniAsserter;
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import io.quarkus.test.vertx.RunOnVertxContext;
import io.quarkus.test.vertx.UniAsserter;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;

@QuarkusTest
public class ValueObjectsTest {

    @Test
    @RunOnVertxContext
    @Timeout(value = 10, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void testGenre(TransactionalUniAsserter asserter) {
        Genre genre = new Genre();
        genre.name = "Test";
        asserter.execute(() -> genre.persist());
        asserter.assertEquals(() -> Genre.count(), 0L);
        asserter.assertEquals(() -> Genre.count(), 1L);
        asserter.assertTrue(() -> Uni.createFrom().item(false)); // this should fail for sure
        asserter.execute(() -> Genre.deleteAll());

    }

    @Test
    @RunOnVertxContext
    @Timeout(value = 10, unit=TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    public void fallingTest(UniAsserter asserter) {
        asserter.assertTrue(() -> Uni.createFrom().item(false));
    }
}
```

pom.xml for project in below - using latest version 3.3.1 of quarkus BOM:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>eu.zderadicka.mbs3</groupId>
  <artifactId>catalog</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>3.3.1</quarkus.platform.version>
    <skipITs>true</skipITs>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-vertx</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-hibernate-reactive-panache</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-parameters</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <systemPropertyVariables>
                <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
              </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <skipITs>false</skipITs>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

What's wrong? Thanks for any help and hints.

Comment: Why would `Uni.createFrom().item(false)` fail?

Comment: @geoand -  I mean test should fail - because it's in assertTrue assertition.

Comment: One more example of weirdness - if I create my own UniAsserter with exact same content as TransactionalUniAsserter, then everything works fine. Only when it is injected, then it does not run the assertion Suppliers.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and reported this bug under https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/36582.
With version 3.5.1 or 3.5.6 of Quarkus, you can consider this bug fixed and your test cases should succeed or fail as expected!